# ¿ HTTP ERROR 500?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, http

Tengo una URL en JAVASCRIPT

```
parametros="cod_documento="+cod_documento+"&cod_tipo_documento="+cod_tipo_documento+"&cod_tipo_documento_seleccionado="+cod_tipo_documento_seleccionado;

window.location.href ="cliente_notadebito_ingreso.php?restore_session=1&"+parametros;
```

El cual me da el siguiente mensaje:

Esta página no funciona La página localhost no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500.

Pero al presionar volver a cargar pagina o presionar Ctrl + F5 me carga la pagina bien...pero al abrir por primera vez la pagina siempre aparece ese mensaje.

Saludos,

Comment: Hola sebamim, un error 500 es un error en el lado del servidor. Debes compartir el código PHP de cliente_notadebito_ingreso.php (y puede que los valores pasados, o al menos una versión simplificada de los mismos, para no compartir datos sensibles) para que podamos ver cuál es el posible error. Saludos.

Comment: que sistema  operativo usa tu servidor web?

Comment: Revisa el archivo `cliente_notadebito_ingreso.php` que no tenga ningún error. Limpia la caché, etc. Por cierto, trata de evitar esos nombres de archivos y variable kilooooooooooométricos... con todo respeto, son un horror. Sencillez en el código, no les llames `a, b, c` ... hay formas sencillas de dar nombres descriptivos y no tan largos:  `cod_cod, cod_tipo_doc` ... Deberías pensar seriamente en una convención de nombres.